# express.static doesn't work in node.js project

Tags: node.js

I have a socket.io project but it doesn't let me use public folder. I would like to launch that hello.js

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugDZw.png

But i only see

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZhjJ.png

I tried everything and just reinstalled node.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require("http");
var io = require('socket.io');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    console.log('Connection');
    var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;

    switch(path){
        case '/':
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            response.write('hello world');
            response.end();
            break;
        case '/socket.html':
            fs.readFile(__dirname + path, function(error, data){
                if (error){
                    response.writeHead(404);
                    response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
                }
                else{
                    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
                    response.write(data, "utf8");
                }
                response.end();
            });
            break;
        default:
            response.writeHead(404);
            response.write("opps this doesn't exist - 404");
            response.end();
            break;
    }
});

server.listen(8001);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using your Express app, but instead a bare [`http.Server`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#http_class_http_server). If you want to use your Express app (which is where your `static` middleware is being used), you should swap out the custom callback for `http.createServer()` with `app` so that is reads:

```
var server = http.createServer(app)
```

Then for Socket.IO integration with Express, you'll need to follow [this example](http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4).